# What is a selenium server?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

i am new to selenium and protractor.I would like to know if selenium server is some kind of compiler for the javascript,if so why do we need to run it first before the test??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the official docs:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server